# Поиск слов с строках

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    char information[20][1000] =
    {
        " 25)Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 26) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 100.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 27) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 9) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 1) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 2) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 3) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 4) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 5) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 6) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 7) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 100.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 8) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 11) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 12) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 13)  Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 14) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 15) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 16) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 18) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 19) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см"
    };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

     }

}
```

Дан вот такой массив. Подскажите как найти и вывести строки в которых содержится слово шкаф?

Comment: [man strstr](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html)